# Unexpected workload differences between SQL servers

Tags: sql-server, performance, locking

So we've been using a workhorse of a DB server for just over 7 years now, last year we began easing into a new server that is essentially better in every way, transitioning one database at a time.  There is one database in particular that we moved to the new server and things got bad...

When under even low-moderate load, queries began timing out, performance on this database and others that had already been transitioned were noticeably slower in almost every way until we transitioned back to the original server.  Once we did, performance on the new server stabilized and the problem database was just fine on the original server.

Some specifics would be helpful!

##### Specs on our current (aging) server:

- Dell Poweredge T640
- Dual Intel Xeon Gold 5120 processor (2.20GHz, 56 cores total)
- 512 GB RAM
- NVMe RAID 1 for C (OS), HDD RAID 10 [8 disks] for D (SQL Data), SSD RAID 1 for L (SQL Logs), SSD RAID 1 for T (TempDB)
- Windows Server 2016 DataCenter
- SQL Server 2019 Enterprise

##### Specs on our new server:

- Dell PowerEdge R7515
- Single AMD EPYC 7H12 processor (2.6GHz, 64 cores total)
- 1024 GB RAM
- NVMe RAID 1 for C (OS), SSD RAID 10 [10 disks] for D (SQL Data), SSD RAID 1 for L (SQL Logs), NVMe RAID 1 for T (TempDB)
- Windows Server 2022 Standard
- SQL Server 2019 Enterprise

##### SQL Server Config

Server configuration is *nearly* identical, except where makes sense due to hardware variances (Max RAM).  Here are screenshots:
[image: General Config]
[image: Memory Config]
[image: Proc Config]
[image: Security Config]
[image: Connections Config]
[image: DB Settings Config]
[image: Advanced Config]

*Enable Contained Databases is not enabled on the new server, however, we don't utilize this feature.

**Before the comments start, I realized the CTFP is outrageous, that's a whole other ball of wax.

In particular, when reviewing our monitoring tools we've noticed unproportionate values when comparing the following metrics obtained from sys.dm_os_performance_counters:

- Transactions
- Lock Requests/sec
- Lock Timeouts/sec
- Average Latch Wait Time (ms)

Happy to provide additional details/graphs if it will help.

The database in question is of decent size, but large for us (120 GB), but has many active writers in an OLTP application.  There are a lot of Page Splits involved with this DB in particular.

Academically, everything about the new server should be able to handle the load of the old server, and then some.

All this info to ask these questions:

1. Is there some difference in how Locks, latches, or page splits are handled on an AMD vs Intel Processor?
2. Is there some difference in how Locks, latches, or page splits are handled on a Single Socket vs Multiple Sockets?
3. Are there any SQL Data structures that may behave differently between the servers?  (this is the only database we make use of Column Store indexes, filtered indexes, and a few other newer/fancy constructs to help speed things up)
4. Are there other factors that should be would cause a database to behave so differently server to serer?

Thanks in advance for joining me in the crazy!

**UPDATE 1**

We run Ola Hallengren's amazing [SQL Server Index and Statistics Maintentnce](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html) script nightly, reorganizing each table at 5% fragmentation and rebuilding at 30% fragmentation AND Updating INDEX statistics.  This is run by SQL Agent on each server with no errors.

**UPDATE 2**

After taking some time to build out ways of replicating the load we were setting without impacting the customer, we started testing out various theories. The winner was @StrayCatDBA who called it with the power settings.  Balanced power options ended up parking many of our cores, the server was never under enough load to get past this throttling, but it was enough to drive the server to struggle enough to impact workloads.

I thank everyone who took some time and chimed in.  Some of the feedback has been helpful in the short term and some of it has helped to start the process of refactoring some of our more "aggressive" queries (and the practices required to compensate).

Comment: Could you please clarify if you execute indexes rebuild and/or sp_updatestats for this database on your new server ?

Comment: Did you verify the execution plans are the same on the old/new server? Make sure the 
 problem database compatibility level and database-scoped config (`SELECT * FROM sys.database_scoped_configurations`) is the same on both.

Comment: @Sergey, we use Ola Hallengren's scripts for this, see UPDATE 1 above for details.

Comment: @DanGuzman I'm afraid I don't have an easy way to validate that as we don't make use of QueryStore and our monitoring tools don't capture this adequately.  Comparing plans has been challenging, to say the least.

What I can say is other databases with an identical (or nearly identical) structure, are not having the same problems once migrated.

Comment: @RyanatCloudRetailer "*I'm afraid I don't have an easy way to validate*" - Easy, take one of the queries that run slowly on the new server, and run it manually on both servers with the actual execution plan enabled in SSMS. Repeat for a couple of other key queries that you noticed performance regression on. Maybe there's a common denominator or maybe you guys follow a similar pattern in a lot of your queries that just needs to be re-written. But either way, it shouldn't be hard to get the execution plans for a couple examples at least, to confirm it's a query tuning problem.

Comment: @J.D. thanks for that answer.  In a perfect world, that is an easy thing to do!  In an Entity Framework world without full query logging, it gets messy.  Query tuning also does not help explain the differences between servers, which is key here.  I need to approach these as two distinct matters.  I appreciate your response though!

Comment: @DanGuzman I missed answering before that Compat levels are the same (150) and config is the same.

Comment: You can use the DEA or RML tools to capture a workload on the old server and replay it on the new server as part of the upgrade validation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dea/database-experimentation-assistant-overview?view=sql-server-ver16 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/tools/replay-markup-language-utility

Comment: @RyanatCloudRetailer "*In an Entity Framework world without full query logging, it gets messy.*" - If you're not able to enable the output of the generated SQL in EF, you can still easily capture the query itself with [the SQL Server Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver16) so that you can re-run it manually in SSMS and grab the execution plan. "*Query tuning also does not help explain the differences between servers*" - Yes, it likely does. Query regression is a very common thing that occurs when changing servers...

Comment: ...even when nothing else changed but the server itself. The SQL engine is complex, there are many variables at play, and the execution plan your query is getting one day can be completely different and change to something that's regressed and worse another day, even on the same server with no apparent changes. When there's a performance issue, comparing execution plans is *almost* always the first place to look which will then highlight what that issue is, whether it's a performance tuning issue or at least to show you what the wait stats are so you know where to look next.

Comment: Side note: "We run Ola Hallengren's amazing SQL Server Index and Statistics Maintentnce script nightly, reorganizing each table at 5% fragmentation and rebuilding at 30% fragmentation AND Updating INDEX statistics." sounds like a bad idea. Fragmentation is much less of an issue on SSDs, and reorganizing is anyway mostly a pointless exercise. Wait til it's seriously fragmented and just rebuild.

Comment: "In an Entity Framework world without full query logging, it gets messy." You can use an XEvents trace to get the long running queries, then run them in manually in SSMS "Query tuning also does not help explain the differences between servers, which is key here. I need to approach these as two distinct matters." So you say, but I've seen no evidence that it's not the case. The compiler certainly might compile differently, if statistics are slightly different etc. EF is known to often produce poor plans, and needs to be coaxed to get the right result.

Comment: And to Charlieface's point regarding: "*We run Ola Hallengren's amazing SQL Server Index and Statistics Maintentnce script nightly*", every time you do this, the cached execution plans for those indexes get flushed from cache, and a new one is compiled the next time that query runs. This is certainly one way you can see execution plans change for a given query when seemingly nothing else has changed on the server. Even more so between two different servers, which have different characteristics.

Comment: You say "we don't make use of QueryStore" like this is some immutable fact. Why don't you enable it? Personally rather than wonder about what's different I'd likely just see if there are specific problematic queries that are using lots of resources on the new server - and if so you can start investigating those and either just tune them if they are doing something obviously inefficient or at least have something specific to compare with the other server

Comment: Confirm that windows power option is set to "high performance"

Comment: I'm circling back here after a long vaca, a longer catch-up time, and more fun in-between.

The winner here was @StrayCatDBA with the power setting.  Simple thing, but we had to do a fair bit to replicate and test without actually recreating the problem for the customer.  Once we were able to do this, we confirmed flipping the power settings from "Balanced" to "High Performance" removed the problem.  If you wanted to post this to an answer I'd happily accept it!

I will post a few other notes in an update to the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirm power settings are set to "high performance", especially on machines with a large number of CPU's.

"Balanced" power setting will throttle down CPU's to save energy and in theory un-throttle them under load.  On a 64 CPU box, 10 CPU's at 100% is only ~15% overall load, which may not be sufficient to un-throttle things.

This behavior results in horrible performance for single queries at really low loads.